# Splitting Regex response column on python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am receiving an object array after applying `re.findall` for link and hashtags on Tweets data. My data looks like

```
b=['https://t.co/1u0dkzq2dV', 'https://t.co/3XIZ0SN05Q']
  ['https://t.co/CJZWjaBfJU']
  ['https://t.co/4GMhoXhBQO', 'https://t.co/0V']
  ['https://t.co/Erutsftlnq']
  ['https://t.co/86VvLJEzvG', 'https://t.co/zCYv5WcFDS']
```

Now I want to split it in columns, I am using following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(b.str.split(',',1).tolist(),columns = ['flips','row'])
```

But it is not working because of weird datatype I guess, I tried few other solutions as well. Nothing worked.And this is what I am expecting, two separate columns

```
https://t.co/1u0dkzq2dV  https://t.co/3XIZ0SN05Q
https://t.co/CJZWjaBfJU
https://t.co/4GMhoXhBQO  https://t.co/0V
https://t.co/Erutsftlnq
https://t.co/86VvLJEzvG
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a description of the behaviour you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what exactly is part of your data. (Does it include the square brackets and single quotes?).  In any case, the pandas [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function is very versitile and can handle ragged data:

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

raw_data = """
['https://t.co/1u0dkzq2dV', 'https://t.co/3XIZ0SN05Q']
['https://t.co/CJZWjaBfJU']
['https://t.co/4GMhoXhBQO', 'https://t.co/0V']
['https://t.co/Erutsftlnq']
['https://t.co/86VvLJEzvG', 'https://t.co/zCYv5WcFDS']
"""

# You'll probably replace the StringIO part with the filename of your data.
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(raw_data), header=None, names=('flips','row'))

# Get rid of the square brackets and single quotes
for col in ('flips', 'row'):
  df[col] = df[col].str.strip("[]'")

df
```

Output:

```
                     flips                        row
0  https://t.co/1u0dkzq2dV    https://t.co/3XIZ0SN05Q
1  https://t.co/CJZWjaBfJU                        NaN
2  https://t.co/4GMhoXhBQO            https://t.co/0V
3  https://t.co/Erutsftlnq                        NaN
4  https://t.co/86VvLJEzvG    https://t.co/zCYv5WcFDS
```